# django error " NoReverseMatch at /polls/"

Tags: python, django

l am following a tutorial and l have been getting these errors!why? i need your help. on the error page it says "NoReverseMatch at /polls/
Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/$(?P[0-9]+)/$']"
please help, l am struggling through this tutorial. the tutorials link"https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial04/"

my index.html

```
 {% if latest_question_list %}

 <ul> 
     {% for question in latest_question_list %}
         <li> <a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{question.question_text}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

 {% else %}
   <p> No polls are available </p>
{% endif %}
```

urls.py in polls app

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

my views.py in polls app

```
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Question
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404 (Question,pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html' , {'question': question})

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls:results', {'question': question})



def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question' : question, 'error_message': "You Didn't select a choice."})
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

my detail.html in polls app

```
    <h1>{{ question.question_text }} </h1>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{error_message}}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <input type = "radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter}}" value="{{choice.id}}"/>
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}
</label><br>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you included polls.urls in root module's urls.py ?

Ex.:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

Comment: l added it, but l added "$" after "polls/" thank you very much!!!!